# Laravel 4 - match string input value to integer field in mysql db

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a select option field in form for showing available language options - like `<option value="1">English</option>`. The value "1" has to be validated against auto increment id in language table, which is an integer. Now when I validate it with `exists:language,id`, it seems to fails as the value is string and the database field is an integer.

First, what could be the most efficient and Laravelish way to handle it ? Second, how can I modify the Input object itself, like changing the datatype of a value in Input object ?

Comment: The string to integer thing shouldn't matter. If it did, the validator would be all kinds of broken, since form input is always in string format. Please add some code, actual error messages, etc., because the problem likely lies elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks Cryode, you are right, the problem was somewhere else. It took me a while to track it though.